# How to bind Windows key in Emacs on FreeBSD

Tags: key-bindings

How do I bind the Windows key to a function in Emacs 29.1 on FreeBSD

Comment: There’s nothing special about the key. There’s nothing special about FreeBSD. You bind it to a function the same way you bind _any_ key to a function. What have you actually tried, and if it didn’t work, what went wrong?

Comment: If I remember correctly, this key is called *Super Key*.  (MS-Windows arbitrarily named it the *Windows Key*.)  You certainly know how to bind *super key* to a command.

Comment: But note that dekstop environments usually take that key over, so (GUI) Emacs doesn't get to see it at all. If you are running GUI Emacs and want to use that key, you will have to convince your desktop environment to let it go: with some of them that might be ... difficult.  To test, go to your Emacs and press `C-h c` and then the Super key: if no description comes up (not even a prefix), then Emacs cannot see the key. Some other action might happen (e.g. on Gnome, you get the Activities screen).

Comment: See [Super Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_key_(keyboard_button)) for a history of the key.

Comment: I haven't tried binding it because I don't know how to refer to it. Is it 'Super' as in "Super-a" 'buffer-menu ?

Comment: C-h c 'Super' has no reaction. On LXTerminal 'Super-PgUp/PgDn' invokes Zoom in/out.

Comment: How exactly is the 'Super Key' referred to in Emacs?